# Email validation- characters length before @ and before dot

Tags: regex, validation, jsf-2, primefaces

I use the following regex pattern for validating the email address that works fine, *BUT* I need to validate the length of characters before `@`, which should **NOT** be less than 4 characters. The same rule I should put for the length of characters after `@` and before dot `.`.

For example, this email address is **NOT** valid: **a@b.c**

However, this one should be valid: **abcd@abcd.com**

How can I do it?

Here is my current attempt:

```
<ui:define name="validation-tag">
    <f:validateRegex 
        pattern="([\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]@[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z])*"
        for="contactEmailAddress" />
</ui:define>
```

Comment: you mentioned that characters before `@` should be less than 4 characters and then you said `abcd@abcd.com` is valid and `a@b.c` not valid I didn't get your point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can impose length restrictions using positive look-aheads with anchors.

```
^(?=[^@]{4,}@)([\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]@(?=.{4,}\.[^.]*$)[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z])$
```

The `^` and `$` will make the string match at start and end, then `(?=[^@]{4,}@)` will make sure we have at least 4 characters before the first `@`, and `(?=.{4,}\.[^.]*$)` will make sure the part before the last `.` is at least 4 symbols long.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eK7vA4/1)

Comment: can you please tell where did you find this?

Comment: @RohanDevaki I can write them by hand, this pattern in my answer is actually OP's regex, just amended a bit to meet all the requirements.

Comment: sir i tried to use it , it is not working, it is always showing error while using that

Comment: @RohanDevaki The pattern is working, you just should be able to use it in your target environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `{4,}` after a sequence of valid characters to specify that you want at least for of them. So try the following pattern:

```
(([\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]){4,}@([\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]){4,}\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z])*
```

Comment: what's the purpose of [\w\.-]* in this case?

Comment: You are right that this is in some way redundant, as `\w` already contains `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. But this is the way Magico wants to validate his email adresses. And as he did not provide much detail on the exact rules I just wanted to point out how to require a minimum of four characters before the @ and between the @ and the dot, independent of what characters he needs there.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with too complicated regexes for email. The user can still make a mistake anyways (like tom@mycompny.com instead of tom@mycompany.com) and you risk to have false negatives.

Maybe something like `/.*\@(.{2,}\.)+.{2,}/` ([test it here](https://regex101.com/r/CeH2Rg/2)) is good enough.